Windows 11 extract all isnt working
How do you extract multiple zip files at the same time in windows 11?
I tried select all'ing my files, then right clicking one of them and pressing extract all, it only extracted one file out for the hundreds i selected for extraction... what gives?

As you noticed, the Windows Extract All functionality only supports extracting/handling one zip file at a time. It opens a dialog for the primary selection rather than all selected files.
You can use alternative programs to extract multiple selected files at once. For example, 7-zip supports doing so:

